Trying to run chatdb / natural-sql-7b, not getting any response
I am trying to build one text-to-sql with huggingface chatdb/natural-sql-7b model, it seems it is getting stuck every time and not generating any result. here is my code. Another problem is its notworking with "cuda". It's showing "torch is not compiled with cuda". Could someone please guide me on this. Thanks in advance!!
import torch
from db import get_schema
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("chatdb/natural-sql-7b")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "chatdb/natural-sql-7b",
    device_map="auto",
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
)

question = 'How many employees are there?'

prompt = f"""
### Task 

Generate a SQL query to answer the following question: `{question}` 

### PostgreSQL Database Schema 
The query will run on a database with the following schema: 
```
{get_schema()}
```

### Answer 
Here is the SQL query that answers the question: `{question}` 
```sql
"""

print ("Question: " + question)
print ("SQL: ")

inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").to("cpu")

generated_ids = model.generate(
    **inputs,
    num_return_sequences=1,
    eos_token_id=100001,
    pad_token_id=100001,
    max_new_tokens=400,
    do_sample=False,
    num_beams=1,

)

outputs = tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
print(outputs)
print(outputs[0].split("```sql")[-1])

Output:
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00, 39.13it/s]
Some parameters are on the meta device because they were offloaded to the disk and cpu.
Question: How many employees are there?
SQL:


Specifically for your torch issue, you need to install pytorch differently if you want it to work with CUDA GPU's the pytorch website https://pytorch.org/ has a section where you can select your constraints and get instructions on how to install pytorch with those constraints in mind.

Hey Karan, thanks for the response. Okay! do you feel result problem also occurring because of cuda?
